# How to make two arrays into a function in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, string

I have two string arrays "Array1[size]" and "Array2[size]". They both have the same size.
I would like to write a function which contains this two arrays but I am having problems in the way that I am declaring them.

I am declaring it like this:    `void Thefunction (string& Array1[], string& Array2[], int size);`

And when I call it I am calling it like this: `Thefunction (Array1, Array2, size);`

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: what error does the compiler give you?

Comment: In addition to answers below: you should use `void` instead of `Void`.

Comment: Thank you, that was actually a typo when I wrote it in the question. But I wrote lowercase "void" in my source code. 

Thank you for pointing that out anyways, because I didn't know that lower case or upper case mattered.

Comment: Everything matters in c++, even whitespaces `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>` does not compile :/

Comment: @Matthieu M. - as of C++0x that is no longer a problem and most modern C++ compilers (g++ 4, visual studio 2005) compile it just fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're declaring a function which takes arrays of string references.  You almost certainly want to take arrays of strings.

Like this:

```
void TheFunction(string Array1[], string Array2[], int size);
```

Comment: BTW, arrays of references are prohibited by Standard somewhere in Chapter 8.

Comment: If you want to pass the array by value (decayed into a pointer to the first element) this will be one solution, but still, using pointer syntax as in Will's solution will be clearer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683367/how-to-make-two-arrays-into-a-function-in-c/1683381#1683381 . If on the other hand you want to pass the *array by reference* (and there you can omit the size parameter) then follow fnieto's solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683367/how-to-make-two-arrays-into-a-function-in-c/1684483#1684483

Answer (score 4):

```
void TheFunction(string* Array1,string* Array2,int size) { ... }
```

Arrays *decay* into pointers automatically.

Comment: In truth, arrays are pointers (and visa versa). The only difference occurrs at declaration, and function parameters aren't declarations.

Comment: @T.E.D: arrays are *not* pointers! When you pass an array, the function receives a pointer. The difference being in the result of the sizeof() operator.

Comment: @Clifford: Not only the result of the typeof() is different, but the type itself is different. This means that the template type deductions will be different.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
template <std::size_t size>
void TheFunction(string (&Array1)[size], string (&Array2)[size]);
```

Comment: +1, this is the only safe solution as the compiler will warrant that the passed in array is of the appropriate size. On the other hand it will not work for dynamically allocated memory.